# How can I remove sidebar's HTML in index pages but not in Blogger Layout page?

Tags: blogger, sidebar

I have a blogger blog in which I have removed the sidebar in index pages adding `<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;index&quot;'>`:

```
<div class='column-right-inner'>
  <aside>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;index&quot;'>
    <macro:include id='main-column-right-sections' name='sections'>
      <macro:param default='2' name='num' value='1'/>
      <macro:param default='sidebar-right' name='idPrefix'/>
      <macro:param default='sidebar' name='class'/>
      <macro:param default='true' name='includeBottom'/>
    </macro:include>
  </b:if>
  </aside>
</div>
```

And it works. But the problem is that if I go to Layout to configure the widgets, there's no sidebar, so I can't, for example, change the order of the widgets in sidebar.

I know I could, instead of removing sidebar's HTML, hide it with CSS. But that would make the blog slower when there's no need to do that.